# tkinter.Entry is returning values I can't explain from the get() method

Tags: python

I am using a simple form to retrieve some information I then want to insert into a SQLite database but the value returned seems to be not a single string.

The form is created inside a function

```py
def formFunction():
    entry_name = tkinter.Entry(myWindow)
    entry_name.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
    submit_button = tkinter.Button(newShootContainer, text='New Shoot', command= lambda: insertNewEvent(entry_name))
    submit_button.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, sticky='e')
```

Then the insert function is...

```py
def insertNewEvent(new_name):
    print(new_name.get())
    db = sqlite3.connect('data/ct.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO t_event(e_name) values (?);''',(new_name.get()))
```

This works if I use a single character in the entry box, but if I use a word, 'TEST' for example, I get the following error...

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 4 supplied.
```

But I am trying to insert a single word, not 4 individual letters. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Change to `(new_name.get(),)`, note the `,`

Comment: So simple, that worked perfectly. Out of interest, why?

Comment: `.execute(...` exspects a `sequence`, using `(...)` is **not** a `tuple`. Therefore it sees your `string` as `tuple`, char for char. You have end a single value to become a tuple with `,`.

Answer (score 0):

As stovfl answered correct above I like making a new window for forms ie:

```
def formFunction(event):
    root.withdraw() # hides your main window
    top = Toplevel()  # New window Opens
    top.title('New Shoot')
    top.attributes('-zoomed', True) # Form will default into full screen
    name = Label(text='Enter name: ')
    name.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
    entry_name = Entry(top) 
    entry_name.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w')
    submit_button = Button(top, text='New Shoot')
    submit_button.bind('<Button-1>', insertNewName) # Button -1 is left click
    submit_button.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, sticky='e')
    exit_button = Button(top, text='Exit/Close', command=top.destroy)
    exit_button.grid(row=3, column=1)
    root.iconfiy() # brings your main window back
```